# Gaussian kernels for arbitrary metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, covariance

Let $(I,d)$ be an arbitrary (pseudo-)metric space. Define the function $$c(i,i') := \exp\big( - d(i,i')^2 / 2 \big)$$

Is $c$ necessarily nonnegative-definite, hence a kernel function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A counterexample is given by the  $4$-cycle graph with path distance. That is, the space consists of $4$ points $v_1,\dots,v_4$ such that $d(v_1,v_3)=d(v_2,v_4)=2$, and other nonzero distances are $1$. Let $a = e^{-1/2}$. The matrix $\exp(-d^2/2)$ is
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & a^{4} & a \\
a & 1 & a & a^{4} \\
a^{4} & a & 1 & a \\
a & a^{4} & a & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
The determinant, according to Sage, is
$${\left(a^{3} + a^{2} + a - 1\right)} {\left(a^{3} - a^{2} + a + 1\right)} {\left(a^{2} + 1\right)}^{2} {\left(a + 1\right)}^{3} {\left(a - 1\right)}^{3}$$
This is negative; the only factor that needs checking is $a^{3} + a^{2} + a - 1>0$.

Comment: The idea to consider $C_4$ comes from the fact that it's the simplest metric space that does not embed isometrically into a Hilbert space.