# Squared exponential kernel with Manhatten distance does not result in positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: metric-spaces, covariance, positive-semidefinite

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Covariance_function#Parametric_families_of_covariance_functions) it is stated that the squared exponential covariance function 
$$C(d) = e^{-(\frac{d}{V})^2},$$ 
where $V$ is a scaling parameter and $d$ is a distance between two points, is a stationary covariance function with smooth sample paths. 
When I use the Manhattan distance or the Chebyshev distance for a specific set of points I get a matrix 
$$K_{i,j} = C(x_i, x_j)$$ 
which is not positive semi-definite. In other words not all Eigenvalues are positive or zero. 
Is the squared exponential kernel only a PSD function when the Euclidean distance is used, or should it be the case for all valid metrics? Moreover, what does it mean for a covariance matrix to not be PSD (which by definition would not be a covariance matrix...)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a sufficient answer in other posts:

[Gaussian kernels for arbitrary metric spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822085/gaussian-kernels-for-arbitrary-metric-spaces)

[Is the exponential of −d a positive definite kernel for a general metric space (X,d)?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885462/is-the-exponential-of-d-a-positive-definite-kernel-for-a-general-metric-space)

For further details on which metric spaces result in PSD kernels of this type, I highly recommend to take a look in the following papers:

[Open Problem: Kernel methods on manifolds and metric spaces](http://www2.compute.dtu.dk/~sohau/papers/colt2016/feragen_colt2016.pdf)

[Geodesic exponential kernels: When Curvature and Linearity Conflict](https://backend.orbit.dtu.dk/ws/portalfiles/portal/119987430/feragen_cvpr2015.pdf)