# Conditions for transformations of kernels to be kernels

Tags: functional-analysis, statistics, taylor-expansion, positive-definite, reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

We are given the results that if $(k_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are kernels (positive definite symmetric functions) then $k_1+k_2$, $k_1 k_2$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}k_n$ (if it exists) are kernels, then we can deduce that $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} k_n$ and $k_1^m$ are kernels too in case they exists.

Is it then true that if $\hat{k}$ is a kernel and $f$ is a function that can be expressed as a power series with positive coefficients $a_n≥0$: $f(t)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n (t-t_0)^n$ then $f\circ \hat{k}$ is also a kernel because:

$$(f\circ\hat{k})(x,y)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} a_n (\hat{k}(x,y)-t_0)^n$$

is the limit of a sum of a linear combination with positive coefficientes of kernels. This would be useful to prove a lot of functions to be kernels. I cannot seem to come with a reason for this to be wrong, but I haven't seen the result anywhere so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you relax "positive definite" to "positive semi-definite", then it is not hard to show that $k_f:=f\circ\hat k$ is indeed a kernel, provided that $t_0\le 0$. Here's a sketch of proof :

- for any constant $c\ge 0$, the map $(x,y)\mapsto c$ is a kernel,
- if $k_1$ and $k_2$ are kernels, and $\lambda \ge 0$ a constant, then $k_1 + \lambda k_2$ is also a kernel. This follows from the first bullet-point together with your assumptions about sum and product of kernels.
- if $k$ is a kernel, then so is $k^n :(x,y)\mapsto k(x,y)^n$ for any natural $n$ (by induction),
- from the above it follows that if $(a_n)_{n\ge 1}$ is a sequence of non-negative real numbers and $t_0\le 0$, then for any $N\ge 1$
  $$ k_f^{(N)} :(x,y)\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^N a_n\left(\hat k(x,y)-t_0\right)^n $$
  is also a kernel.
- The only thing left now is to check that the pointwise limit $k_f$ is also positive definite. This follows because, for all $m\ge 1$ and $(x_1,u_1),\ldots,(x_m,u_m)\in \mathcal X\times \mathbb R$, we have
  $$\sum_{i=1}^m u_i k_f(x_i, x_j) u_j = \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^m u_i k_f^{(N)}(x_i, x_j) u_j\ge 0.$$

---

However if you require that $k_f$ is positive definite, then the answer can be **no** : in general we can't expect $k_f$ to be positive definite. You can have a look at the counterexamples provided in these two answers :

- [Gaussian kernels for arbitrary metric spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822085/gaussian-kernels-for-arbitrary-metric-spaces)
- [Is the exponential of $−d$ a positive definite kernel for a general metric space $(X,d)$ ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885462/is-the-exponential-of-d-a-positive-definite-kernel-for-a-general-metric-space)

Comment: Thank you nice answer!!

Comment: Do you know if there is any result that gives some stronger requirements for the transformation to send kernels into kernels? Also, do you know if there is any characterisation for functions that have power series with non negative coefficients? (more than the ones over their derivatives of every order)

Comment: Hmmm, the only related result I'm aware of is Lemma 4.12 in the book [Support Vector Machines](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-77242-4) by Christmann and Steinwart. Basically it says that if $f$ can be represented as a Fourier series, then
$$k:(x,y)\mapsto \prod_{i=1}^d f(x_i-y_i) $$
is a kernel. But that's not exactly the kind of result you want.